# Can't login to ITunes Connect

Tags: app-store-connect

Can't login to ITunes Connect since yesterday, after inputting my username and password and hitting the login button, it displays blank page on chrome and safari.

Anyone having the same problem?

Thanks

Comment: This is considered off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I had the same problem too. It resolves itself after some time. For me it took a minute but it may last longer. In the past days Apple had huge problems with iTunes, iTunesConnect and the AppStores.

On the blank screen try to guess where a button is and click on it. That might resolve it (thats what helped me).

Hope it helps :)